# Performance issue with usage of regex_substr

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a condition in a very complex query which is something like

```
and regexp_substr(service.name, '\d+') = ?
```

When i run explain plan and check in production this simple filter is causing lot of performance problem.

Any ideas as to how I achieve the goal and yet have better performance?
Heard about recursive QTE, but it sounds far fetched.

The goal being take the digits from service.name and compare with input.

```
Sample data of service.name field would be like
AB 12345
AB1234567
AB     12345
AB:352356
```

No fixed pattern, should pull digits out of them and compare with input.

Comment: Recursive CTE won't help you, it's got nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Please be more specific about the data your column contains and what you search. Give a typical example.

Comment: Well any idea, if there is any elegant solution to this problem?
I provided sample data.

Comment: Looks like using `service.name LIKE '%' + ? + '%'` would do what you need?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. But still there is lots of performance overhead with that. Query is very slow (as expected with like %%).
My requirement seems simple to me but unable to improve performance without adding  anew index.

Comment: You won't be able to make that perform well through different SQL alone, no matter what you do. Adding a trigger that pulls out the required value into a separate column that has an index on it (or a persisted computed column with an index) might be your only chance to get query performance up.

Answer (score 2):

when you use `regexp_substr` if you have index on `service.name` it won't be used, also `regexp_substr` causes switches  between java and sql/pl/sql machines, what you can try to do is

option 1) create index on function 'regexp_substr(service.name, '\d+')' or
option 2) try to use `like` it will be something like this `service.name like '%<here is your number>%'`

Comment: The `LIKE` will be faster than the regex, but it will still not use an index *and* scan the entire table unless you remove the `%` from the start of the pattern.